# Inserting date and Timestamp giving error

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I want to insert `Current_timestamp` in an Oracle table. And,I have tried things like `to_timestamp(current_timestamp,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS:FF')` but its giving error as

```
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
01830. 00000 -  "date format picture ends before converting entire input string"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Also thanks a lot for your answers when i did    `'select current_timestamp,systimestamp from dual;`' then it gave me

```
'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP                    
--------------------------------------
25-NOV-16 12.03.04.605812000 PM ASIA/C 
ALCUTTA ' whereas when i did -'select systimestamp from dual;' I got 'SYSTIMESTAMP                         
--------------------------------------
25-NOV-16 06.33.04.789680000 AM +00:00
```

'.

Now i want to insert in the format **25-NOV-16 06.33.04.789680000** along with many other feilds. 
Kindly help.

Comment: What data type is the column? If it's a `TIMESTAMP` (and it should be), then all you have to use is `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Also note: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is the timestamp at the *client*. Depending on your requirements you may want to use `SYSTIMESTAMP` instead, which is the timestamp at the *server*.

Comment: Check the format of `current_timestamp` by doing `SELECT current_timestamp FROM dual` ... I doubt your format mask is correct.

Comment: ***Never***, _ever_ call `to_timestamp()` on a value that is already a timestamp. You are just converting that first to a varchar and then *back* to a timestamp which it was to be begin with. `timestamp` (and `date`)  columns do **not** have "a format". You insert the value, and you apply formatting of them when _displaying_ the value. So "*I want to insert in the format*" is a wrong assumption.

Comment: To expand on @a_horse_with_no_name's comment - `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` values do not have a "format" - they are stored as binary values with internal fields named YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, and SECOND. To display DATEs and TIMSTAMPs in whatever format you like you use the `TO_CHAR` function. If you have character data which represents a DATE or TIMESTAMP you can use the `TO_DATE` or `TO_TIMESTAMP` functions to convert your character string to a DATE or TIMESTAMP. But for values which are *already* of types DATE or TIMESTAMP, such as SYSDATE or SYSTIMESTAMP, no conversion is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CURRENT_TIMESTAMP](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions038.htm#SQLRF00629) returns the current date and time in the session time zone, in a value of datatype `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

In case you need a `TIMESTAMP` value you can do `CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP)` or even much simpler, use [LOCALTIMESTAMP](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions079.htm).

According to your updated question it seems you like to insert time at time zone or your database server which is **UTC**, not "Asia/Calcutta".

In this case use `CAST(SYSTIMESTAMP AS TIMESTAMP)` or simply `SYSTIMESTAMP`, Oracle will cast it internally.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ed Gibbs said if your column is `TIMESTAMP` then simply use:

```
insert into yourtable select current_timestamp from dual;
```

Or your column is `VARCHAR` and want to change the format then:

```
insert into yourtable select to_char(current_timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI:SS:FF') from dual;
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks a lot for your answers when i did    'select current_timestamp,systimestamp from dual;' then it gave me 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP                    
--------------------------------------
25-NOV-16 12.03.04.605812000 PM ASIA/C 
ALCUTTA ' whereas when i did -'select systimestamp from dual;' I got 'SYSTIMESTAMP                         
--------------------------------------
25-NOV-16 06.33.04.789680000 AM +00:00 '.

Comment: @JSapkota, maybe "your machine" is ambiguous, better use "your current session". This can be different to time zone of your machine (although by default they are the same)